# How to create a custom data viewer on top of QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I was exploring the possibility of creating a simple Data Viewer based on QGIS.

I would like to create an simple application that will open QGIS up with a limited set of tools & menus. QGIS would open up with a given Project file and data (in shapefile format).

Preferably, I'll like to make a stand alone installation program, that will configure QGIS and copy the data like I have mentioned above.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a [Create an application based on a set of QGIS libraries in Python](http://gis-lab.info/qa/qgis-standalone.html) tutorial on creating a standalone app that is very similar to your description (scroll page to the bottom to see the result). Unfortunately it is in Russian, but I suppose Google Translate will provide some help.

Also, you may find some inspiration from [GeoApt](https://github.com/g-sherman/GeoApt) (a spatial data browser based on QGIS).